# Neo4J, Spring Data. How to query Relationship entity?

Tags: java, spring, neo4j, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j

I use Neo4J database with Spring Data. I am unable to query (with custom query) a relationship directly to my Relation entity which looks like that:

```
@RelationshipEntity(type = "OCCURS_WITH")
public class Relation {

    @GraphId
    private Long id;

    @StartNode
    @Fetch
    private Hashtag from;

    @EndNode
    @Fetch
    private Hashtag to;

    @GraphProperty(propertyType = long.class)
    private Long[] timestamps = new Long[0];

    private boolean active;

    // getters, setters
}
```

I have also a repository interface as follow:

```
public interface RelationRepository extends CRUDRepository<Relation> {
    @Query(value = " MATCH (h1)-[rel]->(h2) " +
            " WHERE h1.name = {0} AND h2.name = {1}" +
            " RETURN rel")
    Relation find(String from, String to);
}
```

But when I query the repository I get an empty `Relation` object.
Everything works well when I am quering to dummy object in that way:

```
@Query(value = " MATCH (h1)-[r]->(h2) " +
        " WHERE h1.name = {0} AND h2.name = {1} " +
        " RETURN id(r) AS id, h1.name AS from, h2.name AS to, length(r.timestamps) AS size")
RelationshipData findData(String from, String to);

@QueryResult
public interface RelationshipData {
    @ResultColumn("id")
    String getId();

    @ResultColumn("from")
    String getFrom();

    @ResultColumn("to")
    String getTo();

    @ResultColumn("size")
    int getSize();
}
```

Is it possible to query directly to my entity?

Comment: you missed labels on h1 and h2 and I doubt that your mapping of the long[] actually works.

Comment: Can you create a test project with a failing test for it? Also with SDN version are you using?